# Formula for $ \det(I + A^\top A) $

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is anybody aware of a formula for

$$ \det(I + A^\top A)\:? $$

The matrix $A$ is just an $m\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, whence $A^\top A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ whose $ij$-th element is $a_i\cdot a_j$.

Yes, $\det(I + A^\top A) = \det(I + AA^\top)$ but I'm after a closed form expression for the determinant.

Thanks so much.

Comment: There is always a closed formula of the determinant as a sum over all permutations of the indices. Do you mean a closed formula in what sense?

Comment: The best way I could see, is to use the formula for determinant as the product of eigenvalues. Then you can use the fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ if and only if it $(1+\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $I+A^TA$.

Comment: @surb: Right - the spectrums of $I + A^\top A$ and $A^\top A$ are related as you say. I only know the spectrum though of $A^\top A$ if $A$ is a vector, not if $A$ is a matrix..

Comment: Hello, if $A$ is a row or a column vector, we have $\det(I+A^\top A)=1+\|A\|^2$.

Comment: @Evariste of course. My notation is supposed to mean the dot product of the $i$ and $j$th column of $A$, which is exactly what you have written.

Comment: @user916196 Oh I see, never mind

Comment: @Jochen yes! I'm looking for a generalization of that when $A$ is a matrix instead of a row/column vector.

Comment: @user916196 I'm pretty sure that the only formula you can get that generalizes $\det(I + A^TA) = 1 + \|A\|^2$ is the one you've written:
$$
\det(I + A^TA) = \det(I + AA^T).
$$ 
When $A$ is $k \times n$ with $k$ small (e.g. $k = 1,2$), this does give you a much nicer way to compute the determinant.